# Viewing of PDF present in code - Yii

Tags: pdf, yii

I have placed a PDF file in folder /protected/uploads. I want to view this file on click of hyperlink. But i am facing the error and the PDF is not being displayed.
**Error**

```
Error 404<br/>
Unable to resolve the request "uploads/viewPdf".
```

Here is what i have done to view the file.
**main.php**

```
'urlManager'=>array(
                        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                        'rules'=>array(
                'uploads/<filename:[a-zA-Z]+\.pdf>' => 'Upload/viewPdf',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                        ),
                ),
```

**UploadController**

```
class UploadController extends Controller
{
        public function actionIndex()
        {
                $this->render('index');
        }

    public function actionViewPdf()
    {
        $filename = $_GET['filename'] . '.pdf';
        $filepath = '/uploads/Tutorial' . $filename;

        if(file_exists($filepath))
        {
            // Set up PDF headers
            header('Content-type: application/pdf');
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
            header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

            // Render the file
            readfile($filepath);
        }
        else
        {
            // PDF doesn't exist so throw an error or something
        }
    }
}
```

and the link in the form. I would like to mention here is that the form belong to other controller not the upload controller
**_form**

```
echo CHtml::link(
        'pdf',
        Yii::app()->createUrl('/uploads/viewPdf', array('filename' => 'Tutorial')) ,
        array('class'=>'btnPrint btn btn-danger','target'=>'_blank'));
```

Comment: The link should read `/upload/viewPdf` not `/uploads/viewPdf`.

Comment: @topher but that just is displaying a blank page..No error is displayed in it. Moreover, if i enter i the following URL :/index.php/upload/viewPdf. It displays and error of Undefined index: filename

Answer (score 0):

```
echo CHtml::link(
        'pdf',
        Yii::app()->createUrl('/uploads/viewPdf', array('filename' => 'Tutorial')) ,
        array('class'=>'btnPrint btn btn-danger','target'=>'_blank'));
```

You do NOT have a controller called uploads, you do have one called upload, this is the problem. Also I believe you should not use the first / when using create url. Try using

```
echo CHtml::link(
        'pdf',
        Yii::app()->createUrl('upload/viewPdf', array('filename' => 'Tutorial')) ,
        array('class'=>'btnPrint btn btn-danger','target'=>'_blank'));
```

One more thing, I am not sure that the file resolves to the correct path when creating

```
$filepath = '/uploads/Tutorial' . $filename;
```

The controller is in a folder, why would /uploads/ go to the correct folder from there? Try using a full path, or detect the path with dirname(**FILE**) and take it from there.

Just to also make sure. You create a link that will look something like this:
/uploads/Tutorial.pdf this will get resolved to /protected/uploads/TutorialTutorial.pdf, is that the functionality you want?

Comment: Even after changing the name to upload i am unable to make the PDF view. It only displays a blank page.

Comment: Enable logging for Yii and also take a look in the apache logs to see if there are any problems there. Sounds like a hard error, something like a ; missing or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Most of what Mihai said is true and should be fixed. In addition try changing your controller to include the `$filename` as a required parameter. This will throw a 404 if `$filename` is not present in the url.

```
public function actionViewPdf($filename){
    $filename .= '.pdf';
    ...
}
```